# Codeigniter 'You did not select a file to upload.'

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to upload a file using codeigniter and no matter what I have tried I am getting back the error message that I have not selected a file when I actually have.

My controller looks like so

```
public function editHeader()
{
    $this->require_auth();      

    $config['upload_path'] = './files/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size'] = '1000KB';
            $config['max_width']  = '1024';
            $config['max_height']  = '768';

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
            {
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                var_dump($error);
            }
            else
            {
                $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                echo('yeah!');
            }               
}
```

and my html is just a codeigniter form

```
<?foreach($header as $row) :?>
      <?=form_open_multipart('admin/editHeader');?>
         <input class="waitForLoad fadeInDown" type="file" name="userfile"  />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Change" class="btn btn-success pull-right" />
      </form>
<?endforeach;?>
```

I have tried the normal solutions such as upping the `max_size` as well as putting the upload name in the do_upload function, but nothing seems to work and I am about to pull my hair out. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `form_open_multipart()` instead of `form_open()` when uploading files.

Comment: Even if I'm not uploading multiple files? This did not actually work... It's still giving me the same error message

Comment: @zazvorniki Yup. The multipart has nothing to do with the number of files and is needed in order to upload any files at all. From the documentation (https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html): `By default the upload routine expects the file to come from a form field called userfile, and the form must be a "multipart type`

Comment: Strange that it's still not working, though. Are you seeing it in $_FILES?

Answer (score 0):

You must use 
`<?php echo form_open_multipart(path); ?>` because we get the $_FILES in controller if we write in the form.

After adding it, if u print_r($_FILES) then you will get the array.

It is necessary when we do the work related to image upload or captcha